# Using Picasso image downloader with base url builder

Tags: java, android, rest, http, picasso

I wanted to know if it's possible to use Picasso in a similar way as Retrofit so that I can create a Builder and pass `baseUrl` and then use `@GET("end/point")` annotation? I need to download a couple of images with different parameters so that would be useful.

Comment: Picasso does not have an API that works this way, though it's an interesting idea. If you need the images directly (vs. being loaded into an `ImageView`), you could see about creating a Retrofit `Converter` that uses Picasso.

Comment: @CommonsWare is there any tutorial/ example to take a look at?

Comment: There are several converters that are part of Retrofit. See [the docs](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). None are designed for images, but some are designed for binary payloads (e.g., Wire). Frankly, unless you have *lots* of these, it's probably simpler just to create a bespoke URL-building method (or use `Uri.Builder`), rather than go this Retrofit route.